# Logo asset is clear on Retina but fuzzy on a standard display

Tags: html, css, image, email, retina

It seems most issues I've found online are regarding assets being fuzzy on Retina. However we are experiencing the opposite: our logo is sharp on Retina but fuzzy on a standard monitor.

The source asset is a vector. We are using Illustrator to export the logo with a height of 60px and 72dpi. I'm using inline CSS to render it at 30px high (in accordance of a few tutorials online from Litmus and MailChimp).

I'm rendering it using:

```
 %img{src: "foo", height:"30"}
```

Some things we've tried:

- PNG, JPG and GIF.
- QA'ing on different clients. The issue arises on three different MacBooks (where it looks good) and three different standard wide-screen monitors (where it looks fuzzy).
- Trying to decide if it's an email thing, or rather, an image thing. However the difference is noticed in both Gmail and Preview (which I realize probably isn't the best approach, but it has been consistent with our findings).

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Is the width also an even number?

Comment: @warkentien: I didn't assert the width, just the height.

Comment: I meant checking the actual width of the image file. You mentioned it was 60px height, but not how wide. This is the width I'm talking about.